# Nuget error after adding AzureCloudServce to existing MVC4 app

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have an MVC 4 application that I want to convert to an Azure Cloud Service. These are the steps I took:

- Update-Package to get everything on the latest
- I followed the steps at [this blog](http://thinkfirstcodelater.com/blog/?p=1922)
- Build Solution (succeeds)
- F5 -> Get error that VS2012 needs to run elevated
- Restart VS2012 elevated -> get this error in Package Manager Console:

  At C:\Users\jlearmouth\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MeetingMinutes\packages\MvcScaffolding.1.
  0.9\tools\init.ps1:35 char:45

  - | %{ [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles <<<< ($_, "*." + $extension, [System.IO.SearchOpt
    ion]::AllDirectories) }

    - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

The solution seems to run, but I don't like this error. I don't know what it means and I don't know what to do about it. Google has similar things but not the same MethodInvocationException... tried their solutions - nothing (mostly uninstall/reinstall MvcScaffolding)

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an error coming from the MvcScaffolding package. Have you tried contacting the author of this package? Go to this page and click the Contact Owners link on the left bar https://nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding/

Comment: Now in conversation with owners of this NuGet package.